# The required output is false, true, false, true. My results are false, true, true, true. Is there something missing in my code?

Tags: java

This is the scenario.

Write a method isLeapYear with a parameter of type int named year.

The parameter needs to be greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 9999.

If the parameter is not in that range return false.

Otherwise, if it is in the valid range, calculate if the year is a leap year and return true if it is a leap year, otherwise return false.

To determine whether a year is a leap year, follow these steps:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step
2. Otherwise, go to step 5.2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step
3. Otherwise, go to step 4.3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step
4. Otherwise, go to step 5.4. The year is a leap year (it has 366 days). The method isLeapYear needs to return true.
5. The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days). The method isLeapYear needs to return false.

The following years are not leap years:
1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500, 2600
This is because they are evenly divisible by 100 but not by 400.

The following years are leap years:
1600, 2000, 2400
This is because they are evenly divisible by both 100 and 400.

Examples of input/output:

- isLeapYear(-1600); → should return false since the parameter is not in range (1-9999)
- isLeapYear(1600); → should return true since 1600 is a leap year
- isLeapYear(2017); → should return false since 2017 is not a leap year
- isLeapYear(2000);  → should return true because 2000 is a leap year

This is my code:

```
public static void isLeapYear(int year) {
  boolean result;
  if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999) {
    System.out.println(result = true);
  } else {
    System.out.println(result = false);
  }
  boolean step;

  if (year == (year % 4)) {
    if (year == (year % 100)) {
      step = result;
    }
  }
  if (year == (year % 100)) {
    if (year == (year % 400)) {
      step = result;
    }
  }
  if (year == (year % 400)) {
    step = result;
  } else {
    step = result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger for each of the scenarios? Note that your final `if` statement has the same body for both branches - is that deliberate?

Comment: Your print is right at the start of the method, before any of the leap year logic. You print true if the number is in the range 1–9999 and false otherwise. All the stuff after that has no effect on the output.

Comment: Yes, I did it deliberately for my final if statement

Comment: Do you actually understand what the `%` remainder operator does? When you call e.g. `isLeapYear(2000)`, i.e. when `year = 2000`, what do you believe the value of `year % 4` is, and why do you believe that? The remainder of `2000` divided by `4` is **`0`**, because `2000 / 4` is 500, leaving a remainder of 0. Since `year = 2000` and `year % 4` is `0`, the condition `year == (year % 4)` is false, which is not what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @NhlanhlaZondi ... so your code deliberately prints the wrong output. In that case I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: @khelwood, thanks for pointing out my mistake. How would one go about resolving my problem.

Comment: @Andreas, my bad I mistakenly confused it with the / operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LeapYear {
    public static  boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        if (year>=1 && year<=9999)
        {  if (year%4==0){
            if (year%100==0){

                if (year%400==0){
                    return true;

                }else {
                    return false; //year%400==0 else
                }

            }else {
                return true; //year%100==0 else
            }

        }else {
            return false; // year%4==0 else
        }

        }
        else return false; //this else associated with upper if
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes and merged ur conditions

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        isLeapYear(-1600);// → should return false since the parameter is not in range (1-9999)
        isLeapYear(1600); ////→ should return true since 1600 is a leap year
        isLeapYear(2017);// → should return false since 2017 is not a leap year
        isLeapYear(2000); 
        isLeapYear(99999); 
    }

    public static void isLeapYear(int year) {
        //Should lie between 1  && 9999
        //If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. ...
        //If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. ...
        //If the year is evenly divisible by 400, go to step 4. ...
        //The year is a leap year (it has 366 days).
        //The year is not a leap year (it has 365 days).
        
        boolean isLeap = false;
        if(year >= 1 && year <= 9999 && year % 4 == 0){
            if( year % 100 == 0){
                if ( year % 400 == 0)
                    isLeap = true;
                else
                    isLeap = false;
            }else
                isLeap = true;
        }else {
            isLeap = false;
        }

        if(isLeap==true)
            System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year.");
        else
            System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year.");
    }
}
```

**output**

```
-1600 is not a Leap Year.
1600 is a Leap Year.
2017 is not a Leap Year.
2000 is a Leap Year.
99999 is not a Leap Year.
```

Comment: it is what I have been looking for.

Comment: ,It's give me this output if I want to vote:  Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year < 1 || year > 9999) {
        return false;
    } else if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

start by verifying that the year falls within the constraints. If it doesn't, just return false and exit. Then perform the other checks to verify the edge cases.

OR:

```java
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year >= 1 && year <= 9999) {
        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```